# Solr & SolrNET connection not working

Tags: c#, solr

I am trying to learn how to use Solr and the SolrNET client adapter for C#.

I can't get past the first example found at [Basics](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Initialization.md).

Is there something I am doing wrong here? I can navigate to the url I use in the code and it's up and running.  The service was set up using the Windows installer from [Installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/solr/installer)

My Solr Instance:
[image]

My object:

```
public class Product
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("manu_exact")]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [SolrField("cat")]
    public ICollection<string> Categories { get; set; }

    [SolrField("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [SolrField("inStock")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }

    #region Overrides of Object

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string that represents the current object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A string that represents the current object.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder("Product\n");
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Id - {0}", Id));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Manufacturer - {0}", Manufacturer));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Categories - {0}", Categories));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Price - {0}", Price));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("In Stock - {0}", InStock));

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
```

My attempts at connecting. I am just in a Unit Test project for practicing purposes.

```
[TestClass]
public class BasicExample
{
    private const string SOLR_CONNECTION = "http://localhost:9001/solr";

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        Startup.Init<Product>(SOLR_CONNECTION);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add()
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            Id = "SomeId",
            Manufacturer = "Samdung of poop",
            InStock = true,
            Price = 92,
            Categories = new[]{ "electronics", "hard drive"}
        };

        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
        solr.Add(product);
        solr.Commit();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Query()
    {
        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
        var result = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("id", "SomeId"));
        result.Should().NotBeNull();
        result.Count.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(1);
        Console.WriteLine(result.First().ToString());
    }
}
```

The Error I get from Add method:

Test method Solr.Playground.BasicExample.Add threw exception: 
SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

The Error that arises from Query (I know this will fail because the add didn't happen, but the message doesn't indicate that as the issue):

Initialization method Solr.Playground.BasicExample.TestInitialize threw exception. System.ApplicationException: System.ApplicationException: Key 'SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Solr.Playground.Objects.Product.SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection' already registered in container.

***EDIT***

I found that my NuGet package didn't install latest. I pulled update and now my errors are different.

When the code calls the `.Commit()` Method I get this error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#im-getting-a-bad-request-error-when-calling-commit

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the core you want to connect to you in your URL.  The name of the default core that comes packaged in that installation is "collection1", so your url would be: `http://localhost:9001/solr/collection1`

Also, you will need to change the way you are initializing your connection.  `TestInitialize` will set that method to be called once before each test, but if you call `Startup.Init()` multiple times you will get an exception.  You can use the `ClassInitialize` attribute instead, which will only get run once for the tests in that class.  Try changing your test class to look something like this:

```
private const string SOLR_CONNECTION = "http://localhost:9001/solr/collection1";

[ClassInitialize]
public static void TestInitialize(TestContext context)
{
    Startup.Init<Product>(SOLR_CONNECTION);
}
```

Hope that does it!  Cheers.